# Windows 8.1 NIC driver issue

Tags: network-adapter, drivers, windows-8.1

I came across a Win 8.1 x64bit machine which will not detect the LAN driver at the start-up but works fine when goes to Device Manager-->Search for new hardware(Clicks) I tried a lot by of things like updating BIOS,updating LAN driver. Kindly help me out to sort out this issue.

Comment: Upgrade to Windows 10 its free https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility/windows10upgrade Just check the box

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer is good, upgrading may not be an option in your case. In most cases like this (which seem to be happening quite a bit in win8 and win10), it's the most recent driver that is causing issues. The solution is usually to roll back the ehternet driver to a previous verion. If you're already in device manager, it's located in the properties for the device.